# In vb.net, how to sort datagrid view column with numbers and texts on column header click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

It seems that on clicking datagridview column header, the column will be automatically sorted based on the column type. I have a column showing some numbers. If column type is string, it sorts "1","20","3" into "1","20","3". If column type is double, it sorts into "1","3","20" which is the result that I want. However, there might be some erros in the numbers and error messages(text) will show in the cell instead of numbers. So I cannot set the column type as double. I want to ignore these error messages and sort all the numbers. How can I do this?

Also, I need to add some background colors to different rows in datagridview. So in the column header click event, I call the bkgColor Sub to achieve this. My question is that how can I override the sorting method in this event?

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Try

        bkgColor(DataGridView1) 'A Sub used to add background colors to different rows in datagridview
    Catch
        StatusUpdate("Unable to sort datagrid view", True)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two different questions.
For the first: have a look to the "Null value" of the DefalutCellStyle: do not put a text if you get a null value.
For the second question: instead of clicking columns headers, creata a ContextMenuStrip and assign it to the grid to achieve the same result: no need to override and a simpler thing to do ;)

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your answer. My problem is that I have to display error messages in cells. So I have numbers and texts in the column. Only when sorting, I want to sort all numbers (probably putting all rows with error messages at the end). My second question relates with the first question because I already used the column header click event. So when I click the column header, columns are sorted and also background colors are added. But the sorting is default by system. I want to change the sorting.

Comment: Do you really NEED to display errors in cells? Personally I prefer to use grid.rows(e.row.index).errortext = "error message".   This will avoid you the problems in sorting. BTW: I have no time to check now, but maybe you can sort columns in another way: if my memory serves correctly, you can customize the column ordering...